# Error when trying to login

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem. When I want to log in, I get "ERROR" every time, although I enter good login details.

I am completely beginner in JavaScript and HTML, so please bear with me :-)

There is code:

```js
function login() {
  var login = document.getElementById("login");
  var password = document.getElementById("haslo");

  var lGOOD = "adi282123";
  var pGOOD = "qaz123qaz123";
  var status;
  if (login === lGOOD && password === pGOOD) {
    greeting = "OK";
  } else {
    greeting = "ERROR";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Zaloguj się</p>

  <br id=login><input type="text" name="login"><br>
  <br id=haslo><input type="text" name="password">

  <button onclick="login()">Zaloguj się !!!</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `#login` and `#haslo` are elements. You must get the input value of their children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. You have set id to the wrong elements. You have to set `id`'s to `input` elements.
2. You have to take the `value` from the input element

```js
function login() {
    var login = document.getElementById("login").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("haslo").value;

    var lGOOD = "adi282123";
    var pGOOD = "qaz123qaz123";
    var status;
    if (login === lGOOD && password === pGOOD) 
    {
        greeting = "OK";
    } 
    else 
    {
        greeting = "ERROR";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
}
```

```html
<p>Zaloguj się</p>

<br><input id="login" type="text" name="login"><br>
<br><input id="haslo" type="text" name="password">

<button onclick="login()">Zaloguj się !!!</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```